# Smallest time + space complexity for longest palindrome in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I've seen many different solutions to the question "Find the longest palindrome contained in a string".

I saw one question on careercup.com asking for a solution in O(n) time and O(1) space:
http://www.careercup.com/question?id=15074748

Is that possible? I looked at this solution:

http://leetcode.com/2011/11/longest-palindromic-substring-part-ii.html

and it seems the best- it's O(n) time and O(n) space though. Is it possible to do it in less space?

EDIT: By the way, does it seem like an unreasonable interview question to find a solution faster than O(n^2)?

Comment: I am pretty damn sure doing this in constant space and linear runtime is impossible.

Comment: Could be possible if you have infinite wordsize ...

Comment: @wildplasser: A likely scenario :)

Comment: Will be hard to find an enumeration. I am thinking primes & Hilbert Hotel.

Comment: Didn't Cantor provide a one-fit-all solution for this using his counting function for rational numbers/tuples?

Comment: @user: I don't think you will be expected to come up with an an `O(n)` algorithm for this problem in an interview unless you are applying for a job where string processing and string algorithms is very essential. The `O(n²)` one is trivial, though.